# Disable AddEventListener On Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable the function I pass to `addEventListener` when the user clicks on submit.  I put code in to prevent user from leaving page if they have entered data on any of the fields.  This works fine.  If the user tries to navigate away they get a warning as expected.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to disable this feature once all of the fields are populated and the user clicks submit.  As it stands, they are prompted to make sure they want to navigate away when they click on submit and I don't want this to happen when the user clicks submit.

I've tried something like the below, to try to unbind the `beforeunload` function based on submit, but this isn't working.  I feel like this is the right general idea, but I'm struggling to make this work as I want it to.

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
  $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});

$(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
  return '';
});
```

The code below works as expected:

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
  console.log('checking form');

  let inputValue = document.querySelector('#myInput').value;

  if (inputValue.length > 0) {
    console.log(inputValue);
    event.returnValue = 'Are you sure you wish to leave?';
  }

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

If the user clicks submit I want the `beforeunload` function to be turned off essentially.

Comment: You can't use `element.removeEventListener` with anonymous functions. If you'd like to remove it at some point, you need to make it into a function that can be referenced by name

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks for the information.  So I have to write a separate function for removeEventListener?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, nope. The function that is to handle the event should have a name. From there, you have the following available: `element.addEventListener('eventName', functionName, false);` and then later-on, `element.removeEventListener('eventName', functionName);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to solve this problem using the suggestion that was made by Bipperty via this SO issue...[Narrow Down BeforeUnload To Only Fire If Field Is Changed or Updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155648/narrow-down-beforeunload-to-only-fire-if-field-is-changed-or-updated).  Ultimately the code below is what I used to turn off beforeunload when submitting the form....

```
var submitting = false;

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
  console.log('checking form');

  let inputValue = document.querySelector('#myInput').value;
  if(inputValue.length > 0 && submitting === false) {
    console.log(inputValue);
    event.returnValue = 'Are you sure you wish to leave?';
  }

  event.preventDefault();

});

document.addEventListener("submit", function(event) { 
  submitting = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you bind a handler using `.on()` you can remove the bound event using `.off()`

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $(window).off('beforeunload');
});

$(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
  return '';
});
```

However, I feel in your scenario you don't really need the `beforeunload` at all if you handle your form submit logically.

I've mocked up an example of how you can logically submit the form if a user chooses to submit the form based on a condition (in this case if all fields aren't filled).

```js
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
  var inputs = $(':text', this);
  console.log(inputs.length)
  var validInputs = inputs.filter(function () {
    return $(this).val().length;
  }).length;
  if (validInputs > 0 && validInputs < inputs.length) {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?");
    if (!r) e.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="http://google.com" method="get">
  <input name="a" placeholder="Input 1">
  <input name="b" placeholder="Input 2">
  <input name="c" placeholder="Input 3">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I was doing this previously, but I was trying to get more specific about my form.  Today if I use the above, it works, but when the user tries to navigate away from the page using a link, the above fires as well.  I was trying to be field specific using the addeventlistener, but now I can't figure out how to disable each eventlistener.  If there is a better way to go about what I'm trying to do I'm open to that as well.

Comment: Are you implying that if, say you have 5 inputs, a user has filled at least 1 field but not all 5 then they are prompted and therefore the form is not submitted?

Comment: If all of the fields are filled in it still prompts the user to click to make sure they want to submit it.  I don't want the are you sure to pop when user clicks on submit.

Comment: See the code snippet I've created for you. Does this gear toward what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm testing and it doesn't seem to be firing.  The rest of my function is..

Comment: I'm using Django forms which is why this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

To prompt the user before leaving a form:

> ```
> window.onbeforeunload = function(){
>   return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
> };
> ```

<sup>See this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080331/2813224)</sup>

---

Use the `required` attribute on each field and you won't need to do all of that. The following demo will refuse any attempts to submit it's form if there's a blank field. It will send to a live test server and a response will be displayed verifying a successful submission.

### Demo

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px
}

[type=submit] {
  margin-left: 200px
}
```

```html
<form id='form' action='http://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='response'>


  <label>Name: </label><input name='Name' type='text' required><br>
  <label>Cell: </label><input name='Cell' type='tel' required><br>
  <label>Date: </label><input name='Date' type='date' required><br>

  <input type="submit">


</form>
<iframe src='about:blank' name='response'></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I am trying to prevent user from navigating away from page when they have not completed form and if they have I am trying to allow the submission to work without a prompt.  Are you suggesting your code will allow me to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tested this demo, yet? It's a real functioning form to a live test server.

Comment: `name.widget.attrs['required'] = 'required'`

Comment: Thank you.  Yes I have the form set up to require these fields.  That's not my issue.  The issue is when I am trying to prevent user from navigating away from the page using the beforeunload function.  I can' t seem to work out how to prevent beforeunload from firing when the user clicks submit.

Comment: Have you tested my demo? After a real submission of data ther page is still there.

Comment: Will your code prevent user from navigating away from a page before they finish filling out the form?

Comment: That;s hijacking a user's ability to navigate, which in turn is bad UX,

Comment: I want to prevent user from accidentally navigating away from page.  They just have to click ok if they have started to fill out the form.

Comment: Can I removeEvent listener on form submit?                      $('form').submit(function() {
                      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload",);                           
                       }); I tried this, but perhaps my syntax is not correct.

Comment: @SteveSmith Sure but am easier way is t=to listen for a submit then use `e.preventDefault()`, see update,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Will explore that avenue as well.  Thanks for your input.  I appreciate it.